# Trying to Overcome a JSDARES Challenge

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, parameters, console.log

Hey guys I'm currently working on a JSDares challenge that I just can't seem to wrap my head around.

Here's the link, it's called "More Information":

https://jsdares.com/?dare=300000000000000000000109

Here is the code I currently have:

```html
function person(name, born, died, knownFor) {
  if(died == 0) {
  console.log("Name      : " + name);
  console.log("Born in   : " + born);
  console.log("Known for : " + knownFor);
  console.log("");
} else {
  console.log("Name      : " + name);
  console.log("Born in   : " + born);
  console.log("Died in   : " + died);
  console.log("Known for : " + knownFor);
  console.log("");
}
}
console.log("Famous people in computing:");
console.log("");
person("Charles Babbage", 1815, 1871, "first computer");
person("Ada Lovelace", 1815, 1852, "first programmer");
person("George Boole", 1815, 1864, "Boolean logic");
person("Grace Hopper", 1906, 1992, "first language");
person("Alan Turing", 1912, 1954, "Turing machine");
person("Douglas Engelbart", 1925, 0, "Computer mouse");
person("Bill Gates", 1955, 0, "Microsoft");
person("Steve Jobs", 1955, 2011, "Apple");
person("Linus Torvalds", 1969, 0, "Linux");
person("Tim Berners-Lee", 1955, 0, "World Wide Web");
console.log("And many more...");
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to reduce the amount of lines I'm using. When I use an IF statement, inside the function, I end up writing a CONSOLE.LOG for every PARAMETER and I can't seem to find an operator or method that will exclude the "DIED" parameter in the ELSE part of the statement. Any tips?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use your `if` statement for the entire function, but only for one line. I've fix your code in the example below, and also tested it on your submission website:

```js
function person(name, born, died, knownFor) {
  console.log("Name      : " + name);
  console.log("Born in   : " + born);
  if (died != 0) {
    console.log("Died in   : " + died);
  }
  console.log("Known for : " + knownFor);
  console.log("");
}

console.log("Famous people in computing:");
console.log("");
person("Charles Babbage", 1815, 1871, "first computer");
person("Ada Lovelace", 1815, 1852, "first programmer");
person("George Boole", 1815, 1864, "Boolean logic");
person("Grace Hopper", 1906, 1992, "first language");
person("Alan Turing", 1912, 1954, "Turing machine");
person("Douglas Engelbart", 1925, 0, "Computer mouse");
person("Bill Gates", 1955, 0, "Microsoft");
person("Steve Jobs", 1955, 2011, "Apple");
person("Linus Torvalds", 1969, 0, "Linux");
person("Tim Berners-Lee", 1955, 0, "World Wide Web");
console.log("And many more...");
```

Comment: Thank you man, it seems so simple now that you point it out. I had the right idea on a couple attempts but just couldn't see the full picture.